# Local Instance and K8s Instance resolve different checksums for same flyway schema

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, kubernetes, flyway

This is pretty unusual as per my knowledge and I'm not able to find root cause.

I have a service that I deployed on one of our environments on Kubernetes. It failed to run with the following error:

```
2020-02-27 11:41:44,178 [instance=] [main] INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter (Slf4jLog.java:44) - Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
2020-02-27 11:41:50,665 [instance=] [main] INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory (Slf4jLog.java:44) - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/ENVIRONMENT (Oracle 12.2)
2020-02-27 11:41:52,460 [instance=] [main] INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate (Slf4jLog.java:44) - Validated 8 migrations (execution time 00:01.063s)
2020-02-27 11:41:53,128 [instance=] [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2019.4.1.1
-> Applied to database : 1659809745
-> Resolved locally    : 1875162162
2020-02-27 11:41:53,129 [instance=] [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService (DirectJDKLog.java:180) - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-02-27 11:41:53,153 [instance=] [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer (AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer.java:101) - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-27 11:41:53,160 [instance=] [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication (SpringApplication.java:771) - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2019.4.1.1
-> Applied to database : 1659809745
-> Resolved locally    : 1875162162
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.domain.app.myapp.MyServiceApplication.main(MyServiceApplication.java:30)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2019.4.1.1
-> Applied to database : 1659809745
-> Resolved locally    : 1875162162
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1108)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:62)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1012)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I repaired checksums using `mvn flyway:repair` and was able to run service locally.
Though K8s was still showing a similar error.
This time, I took these checksums manually from the error logs of K8s instance (`Resolved Locally`) and put these checksums one by one in flyway schema.
This got K8s instance running but now my local instance fails giving checksum error.

Any ideas where I might be taking the wrong approach here?
Database host for both local and K8s instances is the same. I'm not sure why only one of these is able to validate Migations at one given scenario.

(I've changed filenames for obvious reasons)

Comment: Check file-encodings, java versions/providers and make sure that the sql does actually match.

Comment: @M.Deinum Versions are consistent. I'm not sure what matching SQL matches means?

Comment: Make sure that upon committing you don't remove whitespaces, add lines etc. to your files. Also are you actually sure the file is 100% (and really 100% upt to the bit level the same)? There must be something different on the file or JVM that is being run which leads to a different checksum.

Comment: Also why are you running local and k8s against the same DB?

Comment: @M.Deinum You were right. I calculated checksum for Migration script file separately and it is consistent with what K8s instance calculated. I'm using IntelliJ Idea for running locally. Looking into why the file was modified before checksum calculation.

Comment: I was pointing to the specific environment by running a local instance of the service. That's why I have the same DB (environment specific) for both.

Comment: Check that you aren;'t doing an automatic cleanup (or change line-endings) on commit.